# Recuperar datos originales luego de modificarlos con ".update" en Firebase Cloud Firestore

Tags: javascript, nodejs, firebase, firestore

Estoy usando la base de datos de [Firebase Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/products/firestore?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI5db6wfvH8gIVFQaICR372QKuEAAYASAAEgI1yvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) con `JavaScript` y `Node.js`.

Accidentalmente modifiqué un documento dentro de una colección que contenía datos muy importantes.

Lo hice mediante el método `.update` como se explica en la sección [Actualiza un documento](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#node.js_8) de la documentación oficial de Firebase.

El asunto es que como estaba utilizando datos de prueba, al modificar el documento no actualicé sus datos correctamente, si no que más bien sobrescribí la información original con los datos de prueba.

Como no hice ningún tipo de backup de esos datos, mi pregunta es...

**¿Existe alguna manera de recuperar los datos originales que sobrescribí mediante el `.update`?**

Comment: No existe tal funcionalidad en Firestore. Y para el futuro inmediato, lo más cercano a respaldos es el procedimiento para _exportar_ la base a Cloud Storage: [Firestore Export-Import](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import).

Comment: @fractalix si no existe una forma de restaurar los datos manualmente, serviría de algo contactar directamente con el [Contact Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact) como sugieren en esta respuesta [Restore database in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35959363/15385861)? Pregunto porque este es un caso diferente a ese.

Comment: La liga habla de Realtime Database, que es otra base de datos noSQL diferente de Firestore ([para más detalles](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore)). Para Realtime Database sí es posible solicitar respaldos, pero hasta donde he visto, no es así aún para Firestore. De cualquier forma puedes consultarlo al Soporte, ellos tendrán más información.